# AngularJs filter not working for fetched data if values are mapped

Tags: angularjs

I have a table in which I am showing live data:-

```
<table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ROW 1</th>
            <th>ROW 2</th>
            <th>ROW 3</th>
            <th>ROW 4</th>
            <th>ROW 5</th>
            <th>ROW 6</th>
            <th>ROW 7</th>
            <th>ROW 8</th>
            <th>ROW 9</th>
            <th>ROW 10</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in dataList| filter:{val4:filter}">
            <td>{{row.val1}}</td>
            <td>{{row.val2}}</td>
            <td>{{row.val3}}</td>
            <td>{{map.val4[row.val4]}}</td>
            <td>{{row.val5}}</td>
            <td>{{row.val6}}</td>
            <td>{{row.val7}}</td>
            <td>{{row.val8}}</td>
            <td>{{row.val9}}</td>
            <td>{{row.val10}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here, I am applying filter on particular row `ROW 4`.
In my directive code:-

```
   scope.dataList = [];
    scope.getAllData = function(){
        ApiServices.getAllData().then(function (response) {
               scope.dataList = response.data;
     });
   }

scope.map.val4 = `[null,'ONE','TWO','THREE','FOUR','FIVE','SIX','SEVEN','EIGHT','NINE','TEN'];`
```

Here I am mapping value for `ROW 4`.
`ROW 4` values are generally, 0,1,2,.. etc. And for '0' I want 'null'; for '1' I want 'ONE' etc. to appear in UI.

The issue I am getting here is my filter is not working. Its working if my value is not mapped for that row but not if the value is mapped. I think there is error in filter code.Can anyone tell me what?

Comment: Need more info here.... ur object is called scope.map but the repeat is looping a dataList. Whats is dataList? Be aware ng-repeat creates an isolated scope...

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov , {{$parent.map.val4[row.val4]}} is not working, also can u tell me the use of it

Comment: So, how can I bind $scope with map method, with ng-repeat $scope ?

Comment: If I clearly understood, this will help you: `ng-repeat="row in dataList" ng-if="!filter || map.val4[row.val4].indexOf(filter) != -1"`